# Generalized Laplace expansion and algebra of alternating functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

What I call the generalized Laplace expansion of a matrix determinant is pp 21 of [this material.](http://staff.math.su.se/mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf) Namely,
$$\det A = \sum_{J\subset [n]} (-1)^{\sum I- \sum J} \det A_{IJ}\det A_{I’J’}$$
where $A$ is a given matrix, $I$ is a fixed subset of $[n]=\left\{1,2,\cdots,n\right\}$, $I’$ is the complement of $I$ in $[n]$, similarly for $J’$, and finally $A_{IJ}$ is a matrix composed of $A$’s rows $I$ and columns $J$.

> The question is quite simple. Do you know the name of this theorem if any?

---

I think this theorem is necessary to define a product in the algebra of alternating functions, what we always do in the elementary differentiable manifold textbooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always known it as "Laplace expansion in multiple rows". It is called Laplace's theorem in Thomas Muir, William H. Metzler, *A treatise on the theory of determinants* (section 93). If you are very diligent and can read French, you may want to look up "Laplace (1772)" in [Muir's History](https://archive.org/details/theoryofdetermin01muiruoft/) (volume 1, pp. 24--33) and check if this is actually in his work (it looks like it is, in ancient notation).